Checking if an External user is a member of a group from their sign-in identity
I authenticate users of my desktop app via Entra. They are created as external members of an External Tenant, and they use their email and password as sign in method. In the app, I need to validate that they are members of certain groups I've created in the tenant. All I have at that point is the email address they used to sign in with. I don't have their User Principal Name.
I can query MS Graph to get a list of all users in a group, but that email address "identity" I have on hand is oddly not part of the profile returned about each user, so I can't check it against the email address identity I have. I do have the User.Read.All permission set in the API permissions for the app.
The question: Is there some way of getting that "Identity" (e.g. testuser1@xyz.com see pic) out of MS Graph?  The functioning code below would return a list of the user's Display Names for a given groupName. I need the identities they use to sign in with.

public async Task<List<string>> GetGroupMembersAsync(string groupName, string accessToken)
{
    var groupId = await GetGroupIdAsync(groupName, accessToken);//gets a group's object id from its Name
    string ApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/";
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{ApiUrl}/groups/{groupId}/members");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();           
    var document = JsonDocument.Parse(responseContent);
    var root = document.RootElement;
    var membersData = root.GetProperty("value").EnumerateArray();

    var memberNames = new List<string>();
    JsonElement value;
    foreach (JsonElement memberData in membersData)
    {
       if (memberData.TryGetProperty("displayName", out value))
        {
            memberNames.Add(value.ToString());
        }
     
    }
    return memberNames;
}


After much further searching, I found this Microsoft Graph: How to look up a user by personal email address? where, in the content, it is explained how to look up a user by Sign-in Name. Seems to work.
